# 405 Method Not Allowed laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, http, hosting, laravel-7

tengo una API Rest desarrollada en laravel 7.2 hospedada en hostinger cuando hago una consulta a un método GET todo funciona bien, cuando empleo otro método como POST o PUT me devuelve este error 405 Method Not Allowed. En un servidor local si funciona bien. Estoy usando Postman para testear la API.

Anexo código de la API del archivo routes/api.php.

```
<?php
  use App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

  Route::post('prueba', [AuthController::class,'prueba']);
  Route::get('prueba2', [AuthController::class,'prueba2']);
```

Anexo código de la API de la clase AuthController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function prueba(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Hello Word']);
    }

     public function prueba2()
     {
         return response()->json(['message' => 'Hello Word2']);
      }
}
```

Anexo imágenes de los test
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tus rutas están definidas correctamente en el entorno remoto? Revisa si en el archivo `.htaccess` no estás prohibiendo el método `POST`.

Comment: Las peticiones post no deberían tener un campo con el csrf token? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf

Comment: @A.Cedano no tengo definido un archivo .htaccess. EL dominio apunta a la raíz del sitio y empleo /public después del dominio para acceder al archivo index de la aplicación. No se si eso sea un problema ?? en local me funciona y el metodo get funciona en en hosting tambien.

Comment: Ah, viendo lo que le comentas a A.Cedano, probablemente tengas mal configurado el server (apache, nginx, ...). El root debería apuntar al directorio /public de tu proyecto, y no a la raíz de proyecto. En la [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment#server-configuration) te dan un ejemplo con nginx `root /srv/example.com/public;`

Comment: Debe ser un problema de rutas o que directamente esos métodos están bloqueados en el servidor remoto. No sé si te den acceso a `httpd.conf`, si es un hosting compartido, por lo general no te dan acceso a la configuración de Apache o Nginx y deberás resolverlo vía `.htaccess`, sea las rutas, si están mal, sea los métodos, si están bloqueados. Si es un VPS sí deberías tener acceso a la configuración y será más fácil definir las rutas correctas.

Comment: ok, probaré creando un archivo .htaccess

Comment: Laravel ya trae un .htaccess https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7.x/public/.htaccess

Comment: Y probe todo y recibo este error: The GET method is not supported for route api/pruebapost. Supported methods: POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soy estúpido jejeje, el problema estaba en la petición, le estaba haciendo una petición http al servidor, cuando ya tiene incorporado certificado ssl. La petición con https:// funciona perfectamente. Gracias a todos.